# Mostrar información enviados por post en otro fichero externo

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

tengo este pequeño ejemplo donde quiero que los parámetros que estoy enviando por el método post en ajax se me muestren en otro archivo php no en la misma pagina sino en mostrarDatos.php, como puedo hacerlo? Mi idea es mostrar al pulsar en un botón un modal de reserva donde introduces los datos, luego si pulsas reservar, oculta el de reserva y muestra los datos insertados en otro modal, pero no se como hacerlo

```js
function saludame() {
  var parametros = {
    "nombre": "dostin",
    "apellido": "hurtado",
    "telefono": "123456789"
  };

  $.ajax({
    data: parametros,
    url: 'mostrarDatos.php',
    type: 'POST',

    beforesend: function() {
      $('#mostrar_mensaje').html("Mensaje antes de Enviar");
    },

    success: function(mensaje) {
      $('#mostrar_mensaje').html(mensaje);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Probando</title>
  <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <input type="button" value="SALUDAME" onclick="saludame();">
  <div id="mostrar_mensaje"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Estás entendiendo Ajax en un sentido totalmente contrario a su propósito. Ajax existe para poder comunicar datos entre cliente y servidor y cuando sea necesario actualizar el cliente con la nueva información. Significa que: 1.  En tu contexto, `mostrarDatos.php` es sólo un intermediario para llevar y traer datos, no para mostrar esos datos; 2. Los nuevos datos deben mostrarse en el cliente, sea mediante un modal, lo cual no es necesario y además no te lo aconsejo, sea en el mismo archivo desde el que lanzas la petición Ajax, que es lo más recomendable ...

Comment: ... En el bloque `success` de Ajax tú puedes habilitar un área del contenedor para mostrar esos nuevos datos, sin necesidad de un modal, el cual al fin y al cabo es una nueva ventana. Los modales por lo general crean una mala experiencia de usuario, por ejemplo, imagina que necesitas comparar datos del modal con otros datos que tienes en la página inicial ... Hoy día, tú puedes concebir tu página como un único contenedor, donde muestres/ocultes lo que sea, teniendo todo incorporado en un solo contenedor. Yo usaría un modal sólo para acciones obligatorias de confirmación del tipo Sí / No.

Comment: No se si acabo de entender lo que pretendes. Aún así, si es lo de cerrar un modal y abrir otro, yo no lo haria de ese modo, sino simplemente sustituiria todo el contenido actual del modal por lo obtenido en la petición ajax, pues seguiría siendo un modal y no tendrias que pelearte con cerrar y abrir otro. Eso si, lo devuelto por el ajax deberia contener todo el contenido del nuevo supuesto modal tal como pretendias, claro.

Comment: cambie el modal, hice que el boton redireccione a otra pagina, y al pulsar en reservar no se me muestran los datos de ajax y lo tengo como el ejemplo de arriba